# VSCode Devcontainer: error while starting extension because another extension could not be loaded that is enabled locally

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I created a Devcontainer in VSCode for SAPUI5 Development.
I added the SAP Fiori Tools Extension Pack (sapse.sap-ux-fiori-tools-extension-pack) to the Containerconfig.
When i start the Container it opens error message:

> Cannot activate the 'SAP Business Application Studio toolkit' extension because it depends on the 'Remote - SSH: Editing Configuration Files' extension, which is not loaded. Would you like to reload the window to load the extension?

When i press reload button it reloads vs code and shows the same error.
I then added Remote - SSH: Editing Configuration Files Extension to the Containerconfig and it's still not working.
When i go to Extensions inside of my Container and hover over the Fiori extension it shows me that the extension is enabled inside of the dev container:

> Extension is enabled on 'Dev Container: Custom Node.js'

When i hover over the Remote - SSH extensions they are grayed out and it says:

> This extension is enabled in the Local Extension Host because it prefers to run there.

I assume that this creates the error. Is there any way to force the ssh extension to run inside of the devcontainer instead of the local host? Or are there better solutions?

My devcontainer.json:

```json
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/javascript-node
{
    "name": "Custom Node.js",
    // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
    //"image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/javascript-node:1-20-bullseye"
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },

    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    // "features": {},

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "yarn install",

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit",
                "sapse.sap-ux-fiori-tools-extension-pack"
            ]
        }
    }

    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "root"
}
```